# TableView Footer is scrolling with the table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I just implemented a Load More button into the footer of my tableView, but the footer is always scrolling with the table. The style of my tableView is UITableViewStylePlain.

Please could you tell me where I am going wrong.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *footerView = nil;
    if(footerView == nil) {
        footerView  = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];    
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 300, 44)];
        [button setTitle:@"Load 20 more" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(load20More) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [footerView addSubview:button];
        [button release];
    }
    if ([songInfo count] > 20 && count < 100) {
        return footerView;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Comment: What would you like to happen when you press load more?

Comment: Load more is working perfectly, and would have no effect on the tableView's footer scrolling with the table.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, `tableView:viewForFooterInSection` does not define a footer for the table, it defines a footer for the section in the table.  You can have multiple section footers in one table.  In the case where your table is only one section, using this method will be functionally equivalent to adding a table footer, but it is NOT meant to be the table's footer.  It is much better practice to use the actual table footer if that's what you want, which can be accomplished by simply assigning a view to the `UITableView`'s `tableFooterView` property.

However, table footers (section footers AND table footers) are both built to scroll with your table.  If you are looking to implement a "footer" that sticks to the bottom of the screen and does not scroll with the table, your best bet is to resize your `UITableView` smaller to make room for your "footer", and add a new view to sit in the spot you just cleared for it.  That way, it will stick in place, and the scrollable region in your table will not overlap with the "footer".

Comment: How do I resize the UITableView when using a storyboard?  Are you referring to resizing in code, or in the xib, or in storyboard editor?

Comment: I was referring to resizing in code.  I don't use xib or storyboards, you'll have to ask someone else.

Comment: You literally saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here if you use the table view in-built delegate method, 
`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`, 
it will appear as fixed at the bottom of the view and it doesn't care about the height of the table view. Even though if you set `tableView.tableFooterView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` it won't work as you want. So as the solution for this, you have to set the table footer view on `viewDidLoad()` (as you are setting delegate and datasource in this method). 
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyFinanceTableViewFooterCell") as! MyFinanceTableViewFooterCell
 tableView.tableFooterView = cell`

And this will work as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around. For plain UITableView, if you want the footer to be not sticky at the bottom, try using the footer in a section with no header. Example: we have one section with headerView and footerView. try using two sections, first section -> with headerView and nil(footer), second section -> nil(header) and footerView.