# How to make UITableView footer for section not sticky

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TableView Footer is scrolling with the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929375/tableview-footer-is-scrolling-with-the-table)

I want to have a footer for each section that will not be sticky and would scroll with the table

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This method defines a view for the footer that is "sticky".

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe the post you mentioned does not answer my question as long as it discusses footer for a table not for the section

Comment: Ah, well I think @jmstone's suggestion of using table view cells as footers below works well for you. It is kind of a hacky solution but it's the most straight forward implementation, and it's the only one I can think of without subclassing table view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a means by which to know when you're at the end of the data set for a particular section, why don't you just tag on a custom `UITableViewCell` that appears as the section footer you want? It's very simple to write the logic within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that would check if the cell being requested is within the data set for that particular section. As soon as the `indexPath.row` being requested is 1 greater than the available data (generally contained in an array, so if indexPath.row is equal to `[array count]`), return your "footer" cell. This will scroll along with the table as it scrolls, since it's just another cell. You can make it look as differently from the regular cells as you'd like.

Additionally, you would need to tell your table view that each section will have one extra row, so if you're saying something like

```
return [array count];
```

You would need to say, instead,

```
return [array count] + 1;
```

in your numberOfRowsInSection method.

Comment: To tag along to this answer, you will need to do `[arrayForSection count] + 1` for the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and also a conditional `if (indexPath.row == [arrayForSection count] + 1) { } else { //configure cell normally }`

Comment: Absolutely. I was thinking that as I wrote the answer but neglected to actually type it. Will update for completeness.

Comment: Ok, if there is no property to set the footer view to "non sticky" then this is a solution

Comment: There isn't. The way the "floating" headers and footers work is that as you scroll, the internal mechanics of the table view constantly update the frame of the header/footer as the content offset of the scroll view the table view is on changes. Since you don't have access to that scroll view, this is probably your best bet.